# WPF Color from friendly name as string

Tags: .net, wpf

Let's say I have a string object "AliceBlue", and I want to create the equivalent System.Windows.Media.Color object based on the Colors.AliceBlue static member.  Does the WPF APIs support this directly, or would I have to use reflection to inspect the Colors class and pull out the correct static member?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("AliceBlue");
```

More information on ColorConverter can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.aspx).